# Selecionar datas que não estão na tabela

Tags: sql, query, firebird

Preciso montar um relatório para um cliente com o faturamento de cada dia de um dado mês.

Até ai beleza, o problema é que agora ele quer que mesmo os dias que não tenham venda, sejam mostrados na tabela com o o valor mostrando zero.

Por exemplo, essa minha *query* extrai o dia mes e ano e faz uma data.

Sei que tem maneiras mais fáceis porém a versão do firebird é antiga pois já tem outro sistema utilizando a mesma.

Enfim essa é minha *query*

```
SELECT      EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.DATAFECHAMENTO) || '/' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM p.DATAFECHAMENTO) || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.DATAFECHAMENTO) AS data
        ,   SUM(pp.valor) AS total 
FROM        PEDIDOPAGAMENTO AS pp 
INNER JOIN  PEDIDO          AS p ON pp.codpedido    = p.codpedido 
WHERE       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM p.DATAFECHAMENTO)    = @Mes 
        AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.DATAFECHAMENTO)     = @Ano  
GROUP BY    data
```

Essa *query* retorna o seguinte

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses são os dias que tiveram algo vendido, porém eu queria que mostrasse os dias que não foram vendidos nada também com o `total = 0`

Ex:

> 01/05/2017 0
>   
> 02/05/2017 0
>   
> 03/05/2017 0 
>   
> ...

Comment: Primeiro, esse dias sem venda tem na tabela? Se tiverem, você pode mudar o `inner join` para permitir trazer os dados de uma tabela mesmo sem dados correspondentes na outra, zerando o valor. Se não tiver, vai ter fazer uma query que gere essas datas em memória ou numa tabela temporária e fazer o *join* a partir dessa tabela. Outra dúvida: `firebird` ou `mysql`? tem as duas tags na sua pergunta

Comment: Não tem na tabela, esse é o b.o, sobre gerar as datas em memória teria um artigo bom ou algo do tipo que me mostrasse? A propósito é firebird

Comment: não sei como criar isso no `firebird`, mas como tabela temporária, a resposta abaixo do @JoãoMartins faz o que sugeri, ele gera uma tabela com as datas e fazer o `left join` com ela, deve resolver o problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se esse script pode te ajudar:

```
WITH RECURSIVE DATAHORA AS(
SELECT 1 AS id
      ,CAST(@PRIMEIRO_DIA AS DATE) as tempo   /*Aqui tem que ser assim -> '2018-08-01' sempre o primeiro dia do mês que você quer*/
  FROM RDB$DATABASE                                  
UNION ALL                                                  
SELECT DATAHORA.id +1 AS id                                                   
      ,DATEADD(+1 DAY TO DATAHORA.tempo) as tempo
  FROM DATAHORA                                                                 
 WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATAHORA.tempo) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATEADD(+1 DAY TO DATAHORA.tempo)))     
SELECT D.TEMPO        AS DATA
       ,SUM(PP.VALOR) AS TOTAL 
  FROM      DATAHORA        D
  LEFT JOIN PEDIDO          P  ON CAST(P.DATAFECHAMENTO AS DATE) = D.TEMPO 
  LEFT JOIN PEDIDOPAGAMENTO PP ON P.CODPEDIDO                    = PP.CODPEDIDO
 WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM D.TEMPO)  = @MES 
   AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM D.TEMPO)   = @ANO  
 GROUP BY DATA
```

Pode ser que eu não tenha feito a ligação da tabela CTE ("WITH RECURSIVE DATAHORA AS") corretamente com seu select então teste e adapte corretamente pro teu caso.

**Porque recursive?**

Em resumo, é utilizado o `RECURSIVE` para indicar que a query vai se repetir, ou seja, é uma consulta que se repete de novo e de novo, cada vez usando os resultados da iteração anterior. Isso pode ser bastante útil para produzir relatórios baseados em dados hierárquicos.

O membro recursivo é associado ao membro âncora pelo operador UNION ALL ou UNION DISTINCT.

[Você pode entender um pouco melhor aqui](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-recursive-cte/) (Ta em inglês)

[image: Exemplificação]

Comment: Putzz Que grande ajuda amigo, muito obrigado. Funcionou

Comment: Por que `RECURSIVE`? Ou é só um alias?

Comment: @rbz Confere minha resposta editada!

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro A cada linha da `cte_count`, ela irá "refazer" o `with`, seria isso?

Comment: @rbz Isso mesmo, por exemplo na imagem, ele executa o `Anchor member` uma vez para ter uma "base" e depois executa recursivamente o que está após o `UNION ALL` pegando como base o resultado anterior, então o `WITH` fica se repetindo até chegar na condição informada.

Answer (score 1):

Pode tentar algo desse género (código não testado!):

```
DECLARE DataInicial AS DATE
DECLARE DataAtual   AS DATE

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TmpDatas (Data AS DATE)

SET DataInicial = STR_TO_DATE('01/' + CAST(@Mes AS CHAR) + '/' + CAST(@Ano AS CHAR), '%d/%m/%Y')
SET DataAtual   = DataInicial

WHILE MONTH(DataAtual) = MONTH(DataInicial) DO
    INSERT INTO TmpDatas VALUES(DataAtual)

    SET DataAtual = DATE_ADD(DataAtual, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
END WHILE

SELECT      DATE_FORMAT(TMP.Data, '%d/%m/%Y')   AS Data
        ,   IFNULL(SUM(pp.valor), 0)            AS Total 
FROM        TmpDatas        AS TMP
LEFT JOIN   PEDIDOPAGAMENTO AS PP   ON  P.DATAFECHAMENTO    = TMP.Data
LEFT JOIN   PEDIDO          AS P    ON  PP.codpedido        = P.codpedido
WHERE       MONTH(P.DATAFECHAMENTO) = @Mes 
        AND YEAR(P.DATAFECHAMENTO)  = @Ano  
GROUP BY    Data
```

A sintaxe ou a utilização das funções pode não estar 100% correta, poderá ter que fazer alguns "ajustes".

Comment: Irei testar daqui a pouco do o retorno. Obrigado

Comment: João muito obrigado, começou a dar conflitos pois como mencionado a versão do firebird é bem antiga e tem coisas que nem existem ainda nele. Mas muito obrigado o esforço