# Retornar consulta sem registro no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, query

Olá. Tenho um sistema em PHP com MySQL de uma empresa de frota de caminhões. Nesse sistema cada usuário realiza um checklist do veículo antes de utilizá-lo. Esse checklist é cadastrado em uma tabela no banco de dados. 
Meu cliente está pedindo uma tela de consulta dos checklist que não foram realizados. Exemplo: ele informa o período de data e o sistema retorna os checklists que não foram feitos naquele período.

Como vou retornar uma consulta de algo que não está cadastrado no banco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então EltonRodrigo, primeiramente bem-vindo! A resposta simples é não. A resposta completa é: você provavelmente modelou o banco sem fazer uma análise mais apurada da regra de negócio. Nessa situação eu teria feito uma cadastro de checklist, onde eu indicaria o veículo, se o checklist foi realizado ou não (um campo booleano status), quem realizou o checklist e data de realização desse checklist. Daria para obter essa informação pela simples filtragem dos checklists com status true.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Silva Júnior. Sim, eu tenho uma tabela com todos os veículos e tabela com os condutores, elas estão com chave estrangeira para a tabela de checklist. Na tabela de checklist também tem data de realização. A dúvida é seguinte: não existe nenhum cronograma para a realização dos checklist e nem data específica, qualquer condutor pode pegar o veículo quando e onde quiser.

Comment: Por exemplo, pode pesquisar pela data na tabela checklist. Suponhamos que o relatório seja mensal, veja quantos checklists foram feitos e subtraia de de 30 ou 31, conforme o mês. Nesse caso, tu usaria a função COUNT do SQL.

Comment: Você pode adapatar o seu código com base nesse post; <https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322203/selecionar-datas-que-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A3o-na-tabela>

Comment: Deu certo!  Eu vinculei a tabela frotas com a tabela checklist utilizando o left join como mostra nesse link desse post que você me passou.  Eu tive que adicionar uma coluna "realizado" do tipo booleana e no Select utilizei a cláusula WHERE com valor "is null". Muito obrigado.